# Additional copy when returning with member function call

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple class `T` containing a member function `T& Add(int)`, and a function `Foo`:

```c++
T& T::Add(int c) {
  x += c; // x is a member of T
  return *this;
}

T Foo(const T& a, int c) {
  T b(a);
  b.Add(c);
  return b;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```c++
void MyFunc() {
  T a, b;
  b = Foo(a, 2);
}
```

When I print in every constructors and assignments, this is the result:

```
construct
construct
copy construct
move assign
destruct
destruct
destruct
```

It looks great. However, if I change `Foo` like this:

```c++
T Foo(const T& a, int c) {
  T b(a);
  return b.Add(c);
}
```

An additional pair of copy construct / destruct appears:

```
construct
construct
copy construct
copy construct
destruct
move assign
destruct
destruct
destruct
```

What's the difference here?

Comment: The difference is that `return b;` makes `b` eligible for copy elision.

Comment: Agreed. the compiler is unable to unpick that the returned reference is the input temporary, so it presumes the temporary cannot be copy elision bound to the return value. One day perhaps this optimisation could be done. Also, did you build with maximum optimisations and inlining?